# C# Concatenate records of string on match

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm generating set of records where each record is made of three strings. The number of records generated are dynamic as the user can add as much as they want.

I need to go through the set of records, and generate / combine records based on two of the three strings and the third string are concatenated. I know this might not be clear but I'm providing some sample date of set of records by user and the what the result I need.

Records generated by user:

Record 1: "**AAA**","**BBB**","DEF"

Record 2: "**AAA**","**BBB**","QEW"

Record 3: "*RRR*","*WWW*","123"

Record 4: "*RRR*","*WWW*","321"

Record 5: "XXX","WWW","421"

Outcome I need:

Record 1: "AAA","BBB","DEFQEW"

Record 2: "RRR","WWW","123321"

Record 3: "XXX,"WWW","421"

Also in what should I store records to manipulate the date as I want?

I'm not familiar with LINQ so if you suggest that I would appreciate some examples. Thank you!

**EDIT**:

I'm generating the strings from looping in a datarow. I can store them like in list of list(string) or anything you suggest.

Comment: What kind of records? Is this Linq-To-Objects or a database driven provider?

Comment: string a = "aaa"
string b = "bbb"
string c = "def"
 simple string variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an `IEnumerable<CustomType>` where `CustomType` is  a class with three properties:

```
var result = records
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Prop1, x.Prop2 })
    .Select(g => new CustomType 
    {
        Prop1 = g.Key.Prop1,
        Prop2 = g.Key.Prop2,
        Prop3 = String.Join(", ", g.Select(x => x.Prop3))
    });
```

If it's a `DataTable` as now mentioned in your question:

```
var result = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new { Col1 = row.Field<string>(0), Col2 = row.Field<string>(1) })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Col1 = g.Key.Col1,
        Col2 = g.Key.Col2,
        Col3 = String.Join(", ", g.Select(row => row.Field<string>(2)))
    });
```

Comment: Thanks the data table answered helped me a lot. will update with question with the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Without more context it is hard to propose an optimal solution. A simple Linq [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might do the trick:

```
// Assuming that each array has exactly 3 elements
IEnumerable<string[]> records; // Initialize this
var groupedRecords = records
    .GroupBy(
        // Group the records by the two first values
        r => new { a = r[0], b = r[1] },

        // Concatenate the matching records
        (k, g) => new { k.a, k.b, string.Join("", g.Select(r => r[2]) }
    );
```

In this example I am assuming that each record is simply an array of 3 elements. You will probably want to create a type that properly represents your records, but the code should be trivial to adapt.

Comment: yes there are always four strings but to make things simpler. I need to store each record in an array (which will hold it's three strings) and then the record should be stored inside another array. Is that correct? An array of array strings?

Comment: If you are using a DataTable, you can easily reuse this code. There is no need to copy the data elsewhere. @Tim Schmelter 's answer is equivalent to mine and shows how to do that.

Comment: thanks mate, it worked. just needed more further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"AAA","BBB","DEF"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"AAA","BBB","QEW"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"RRR","WWW","123"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"RRR","WWW","321"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"XXX","WWW","421"});

            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => new  {col1 =  x.Field<string>("Col1"), col2 = x.Field<string>("Col2") })
                .Select(x => new { 
                    col1 = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Col1"),
                    col2 = x.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Col2"),
                    col3 = string.Join("",x.Select(y => y.Field<string>("Col3")).ToArray())
                })
                .ToList();

        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I'm going to give best answer to Tim since he answered first. But thanks man you gave out a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// here's the solution thanks to jdweng and Tim - I adjusted it to work with 5 columns based on 3 columns.
var result = toDisplay.AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(x => new { Col1 = x.Field<string>("rItem"),
                                 Col2 = x.Field<string>("rMaterial"),
                                 Col3 = x.Field<string>("rSpecs")})
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Col1 = g.Key.Col1,
                Col2 = g.Key.Col2,
                Col3 = g.Key.Col3,
                Col4 = String.Join(", ", g.Select(row => row.Field<string>("rQuantity"))),
                Col5 = String.Join(", ", g.Select(row => row.Field<string>("rOptional"))),
            });
```